# Writing a django ORM query

Tags: python, django

I'm new to both django and python.  I'm trying to figure out the best (most performant) way to do a query.

Here is my models:

```
class Immunization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    effective_duration = TimedeltaField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    birthday = models.DateField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

'''
    ImmunizationRecord is a specific date an immunization was administered to a given patient.
'''
class ImmunizationRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient')
    immunization = models.ForeignKey('Immunization')
    date_administered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The query I am trying to perform is:

***Get all Immunizations that a patient hasn't received in the past Immunizations.effective_duration.***

So far I am doing something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    all = Immunization.objects.all()
    done = ImmunizationRecord.objects.filter(patient__name=self.request.user)

    for r in done:
        #TODO: add date check for expiry
        all = [s for s in all if r.immunization.name != s.name] 

    context['available_list'] = all
    return context
```

Comment: you want all immunizations that where the date administered less todays date is greater then the effective duration?

Comment: Or do you want all immunizations that a person doesn't currently effectively have?

Comment: All vaccinations the patient NEEDS.  So if they got the vaccination 20 days ago, and the effective_duration = 19, then they are 1 day overdue and they NEED the vaccination.

Comment: The cardinality of both immunizations and records is going to be low; doing a software level join will be totally fine. Could consider caching in-process the `list(Immunization.objects.all())` for a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *might* improve things a bit.

```
Import numpy
Import datetime 
recent_immunizations = ImmunizationRecord.objects.filter(patient=request.user).order_by(date_administered).reverse()


output = []
for r in recent_immunization:
   if (datetime.datetime.today() - r.date_administered) > r.immunizations.effective_duration:
       output.append(r.immunization.name)
```

Waring this code is not tested!

Comment: `effective_duration` and `name` are not functions.

Comment: They are related and they should be accessible through this method.

Comment: They are not functions, but properties. You will get `object is not callable` exception.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid your right the parenthesies at the end should be taken out

Answer (score 0):

> Get all Immunizations that a patient hasn't received in the past
>   `Immunizations.effective_duration`.
>
> All vaccinations the patient NEEDS. So if they got the vaccination 20
>   days ago, and the effective_duration = 19, then they are 1 day overdue
>   and they NEED the vaccination.

We need to get a patient; and then whatever immunization they *have* received. Then we need to know what is the difference in days from today and the date each immunization was administered; if that difference is less than the effective days; the patient needs that immunization again.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()

p = Patient.objects.get(pk=1) # Get some patient
imm = ImmunizationRecord.objects.filter(patient=p) # This patient's record

still_needed = []

for record in imm:
   # How many days have passed since the immunization was administered?
   days_since = (today - record.date_administered).days

   if record.immunization.effective_duration < days_since:
      still_needed.append(record.immunization)
```

Comment: What if they have never been immunized before and there is no ImmunizationRecord?  That is why my code first grabs all Immunizations and then reduces from there.

Comment: Simply filter it out; `Patient.objects.exclude(pk__in=ImmunizationRecord.objects.values_list(patient__pk, flat=True))`

Comment: The view shows immunizations needed by the currently logged in patient.  I'm not sure how to be any more clear about that.  Your code appears to be grabbing all patients who have never been immunized before.  I stand by my assessment that you must first grab all immunizations and remove those that the patient has already had within the effective duration of the immunization.

Comment: So the end output should be a list of immunizations the patient needs.  Not a list of patients that have never been immunized before.